# JavaScript code to change value of text-area just through clicking different images

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Overview : I am making 9*9 table in html within which I will fill different images (of alphabets i.e. 'A' or 'B') what I want is to make it such a way that as user clicks an image then a corresponding character is input in text-box below it.

Such as user clicks on image of 'A' then 'A' will be entry of text-box next user clicks on 'Z' then new entry will be 'AZ' (without single quotes ;-) Obviously).
Can anyone help me out with any example of given JavaScript code.

Comment: show us our html code, especially how you created your 9x9 table

Comment: i created it by using <table> . does that has anything to do with what i asked, anyways i got what i wanted. :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation to make this very clean.  Personally I would just use the alt attribute of my images and not bother with data attributes or IDs.  The relevant part is here:

```
$(tableElement).on('click', 'img', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    label.innerText = label.innerText + target.alt;
});
```

But you can find a working, randomly generated version (minus image sources) here: http://jsfiddle.net/K79FQ/

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery, you could do the following.

```
<input id='textbox' type='text' />

<div id='container'>
    <img src="a.png" id="A" data-char='A'/>
    <img src="b.png" id="B" data-char='B'/>
    <img src="c.png" id="C" data-char='C'/>
</div>
```

I've added a container div, to make the click event slightly more specific.  If there was no container and the click event was purely on the img selector, it would fire for clicking on any image on the page.

the JS

```
$('#container').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
     var char = $(this).attr('data-char');
     var textboxValue = $('#textbox').val();
     $('#textbox').val(textboxValue + char);

});
```

There are many ways to do the same thing.  I like this approach the most.

**EDIT:**
Updated as suggested by Brandon

Comment: This works well, but you are binding a click handler to each img individually.  This seems like a great candidate for the optimizations that event delegation can offer, and, since you are already using jquery's on, your code would need minimal modification.

Comment: @Brandon you are right, I rushed this piece, and I would definitely change it to use the event delegation.  Will update now.

Answer (score 0):

(Why does everyone assume jQuery?)

I'm using event delegation, and assuming that the images are set as the background to the cells. I've only completed this for the first row, and the nbsp's won't be necessary when css is applied to the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tblLetters">
    <tr><td data-lett="A">&nbsp;</td><td data-lett="B">&nbsp;</td><td data-lett="C">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="results">


<script type="text/javascript">
var addEvent = function (elem, eventType, func) {
    if ( elem.addEventListener )
        addEvent = function (elem, eventType, func) {
            elem.addEventListener(eventType, func, false);
        };
    else if ( elem.attachEvent )
        addEvent = function (elem, eventType, func) {
            elem.attachEvent('on' + eventType, func);
        };
    addEvent(elem, eventType, func);
};

var delegateEvent = function (elem, childElems, eventType, func) {
    addEvent(elem, eventType, function (e) {
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var elem = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        if ( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == childElems ) {
            func(elem);
        }
    });
};
function updateResults(cell) {
    document.getElementById('results').value += cell.getAttribute('data-lett');
}
delegateEvent(document.getElementById('tblLetters'), 'td', 'click', updateResults);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but why not use jquery?  it does all the right things.  Saves you time, save you cross-browser issues.  Use it while it's ahead.  For one, look how much code it has saved by using jquery.

Comment: Yes, I agree, jQuery is wonderful; but the OP hasn't mentioned it.

Comment: We use jquery for event delegation here because jquery is pretty much ubiquitous and don't really feel like copying and pasting tons of boilerplate when three lines are sufficient.  Also, if someone is asking a question like this we probably don't need to be bombarding their head with a giant block of code (with no explanation might I add) accounting for the differences between addEventListener and attachEvent

Comment: I don't want to do all the OPs work for him, so he can expend a little effort to understand the code. Or he can ignore it if he prefers.